# How do I find the location of the vernal equinox?

Tags: astronomy

Despite doing a bit of internet research, I cannot seem to find out how to find the actual location of the vernal equinox. As I understand it, the equinox is the location that the equator crosses the celestial plane, and the location of the vernal equinox is the location on the equator that crosses the celestial plane. What is the best way to find that location?

Comment: There is almost nothing to "find" (as in no celestial object) at the vernal equinox. So what exactly are you looking for? Just the approximate position?

Comment: Yes, I came across it reading an article on orbital mechanics related to ascending and descending nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Point_of_Aries

There is also First Point of Libra.

Comment: Okay, so there actually is a constant location that you can look up at any given date? Thanks!

Comment: The position isn't constant. Due to precession (mainly) it moves, which is why the First Point of Aries is now in Pisces.

Comment: This answer is not exactly right. In this era in solistial calendar you are right. but the question is about finding the point based on the tropical calendar. the moment of vernal equinox is the location where it is exactly noon on the equator in the equinox moment.

Comment: This link only answer isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

[image: An illustration of sun and earth alignment on March 20th]The earth equator crosses the ecliptic plane in 2 points or nodes. When you consider the axis between the 2 nodes (from the ascending node to the descending node), this axis will always points to the vernal equinox . In the spring, this axis and the sun are aligned, meaning that the sun is found at the vernal equinox during that time of year (March 21st or 20th). Because of the Earth's nutation (wobbling), the tilting angle changes over a period of 20,000 years which in turn changes the location of the vernal equinox as the nodes axis changes direction. I believe that the location of equinox is in the constellation of Pisces right now.